# How can I sketch this complex number set?

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

Describe and sketch the set of complex numbers satisfying the conditions:

(|z|−1)(|z|−2)≤0 and Im(z)>0.

I have done the previous part where I had to sketch (|z|−1)(|z|−2)≤0 and Im(z)>0, and that was fine, but now that the (|z|−2) has been added in I am not sure what to do.
I have tried expanding to get (|z|)^2-3|z|+2≤0 but am also not sure how to graph that either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: In order for a product of two real numbers to be negative, what?

Comment: Try to use $x^2+y^2=|z|^2$